How create a persistent system with Petalinux?
I've been stuck on this problem for several days and I'm having trouble finding resources, so I'm calling on the community.
I have created a Linux system on a Zynq-7000 type card using Petalinux. This system works very well but it used an initramfs which means that my memory was not persistent. I'd now like my system to be persistent, so I've opted for a jffs2 file type, but I'm struggling to find resources on how to do this next.
I've enabled the new file system in the petalinux configuration, I've also enabled all the necessary support in the kernel, u-boot and petalinux in general.
However, I can't get my system to load. I understand that I need to partition my card, but how do I do that?
At the moment I was going to do it the same way as for my ramdisk, I launch u-boot, from u-boot I load my image.ub which contains all my system and I find myself with my system launched. I managed to launch my rootfs.cpio.u-boot but it's still a non-persistent system. I then tried bootm <Addr_Fit_Image> <Addr_rootfs.jffs2> <Addr_dtb> but if I do that I get a ‘Wrong ramdisk format’ error from the fit image.
Could someone shed some light on this, what am I missing?
All the best,
Boune
